# Why is it so hard to find who liked your stuff on Google+?

Tags: google-plus

Contrary to Facebook, if you want to see who liked your stuff on Google+, it always takes 100 years to find out. Why?

**What is the easiest thing to click to know who +1 your stuff?**

Also if the feed tells me Eric like my photo...I cannot click on his name in the feed. It's just plain stupid.

Comment: Is there an actual question here, or are you just ranting?

Comment: Well the question is: where do you actually click to find Eric? It is not trivial in Google+.

Comment: Because Google UIs are often terrible, Google thinks that infinite storage is enough of a selling point >:-)

Answer (score 1):

In your Google+ Notifications (that's the little bell in the upper right), just click on the card that tells you "Eric +1'd your photo" and it will pop up your photo post.

If you want more information on who +1'd/shared/etc., click "View post" at the bottom.

Then, when you have the full view of the post, open the menu (looks like a wide "V") and click "View post activity". There you'll see all the people who +1'd and/or shared the post. Click on Eric's name to see his profile.

It would probably be nice if you could click the link for the person's profile in the first step, but since G+ consolidates notifications, that would be problematic for posts with a lot of activity on them, so I'm sure it's a conscious design decision. (And even Facebook requires some extra clicks if more than a couple people have "Liked" a post of yours.)

Comment: Problem is: I don't see any post activity...even though someone like my photo. Really strange. I only see, edit post, delete post...etc. Although in some other posts, I do see post activity and in particular if there's someone in my circles that like my posts then I clearly see them and **they are clickable**. But for strangers...it's a different story. Don't know why?

Comment: @Love: Have you blocked or muted anyone? Could it be one of these people? Do you have any Pages? Do you have multiple Google Accounts? Could the person have retracted their +1?

Comment: Perhaps they retracted. But in any case I find that G+ somehow overcomplicate things in this regard. People should be clickable (or at least more info when mouse over their name) in notification bar already IMHO.

Answer (score -1):

If your on computer you can press anywhere on the post just not what the person posted and then under it will come up in blue,[image] 'publicly shared' (if you publicly shared it) and 'view activity' if you press 'view activity' you can see who liked, shared and commented on your post[image]